# From several sets of data, sum the highest numbers for each Id

Tags: google-sheets, numbers, set

I have 3 sets of data, all consisting of 1 column with a list of unique IDs and the other with integers. Some of the unique IDs (with their integer) appear in more than 1 set, others don't.

```
ColA        ColB        ColD        ColE        ColF        ColG
UniqueIDs1  Integers1   UniqueIDs2  Integers2   UniqueIDs3  Integers3
```

I want to sum all the integers in all sets, BUT if there's a duplicate, only sum the highest between the 3 (or the 2 if the match is only between 2 sets).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula computes such a sum.

```
=sum(query({A:B; D:E; F:G}, "select max(Col2) group by Col1"))
```

1. `{A:B; D:E; F:G}` stacks the columns of your sheet (you may want to use A2:B if 1st row are headers). The result is an array with two columns, Id in Col1, and integer in Col2.
2. `Query` selects the maximal element of second column for each Id.
3. `Sum` adds those.